# fs readfile position if already at end of file

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I'm writing something that is effectively "tailing" a file - every now and then the browser polls back and says "I read up to position 23123, give me anything more".   I've written this function which is supposed to give me anything new:

```
async function readNew( filename, mark )
{
    var fileDescriptor = await fs.open( filename, "r" );
    var buffer = new Buffer( 32768 );
    var result = await fs.read( fileDescriptor, buffer, 0, buffer.length, mark );
    await fs.close( fileDescriptor );
    return result;
}
```

and it works perfectly *if* there is something new.  If there's not, for some reason it goes back to the beginning and reads the entire file!    So for instance, if mark is 16427 - and the file is of size 16427 - I get 16427 bytes read - and what I want is 0.

Any ideas how I can fix this reliably, and with some level of performance?
  *Most* of the time, there won't be any changes - so I want that case to be as fast as possible.

Answer (score 1):

found a really horrible answer - which is to go back, read two bytes - and if I only get one - decide that I'm at the end - but it seems there *must* be a better way?

```
async function readPart( filename, mark )
{
    var fileDescriptor = await fs.open( filename, "r" );
    var buffer = new Buffer( 32768 );
    var result = await fs.read( fileDescriptor, buffer, 0, 2, Math.max( 0, mark-1));
    if (result[0] == 1)
        return [0, new Buffer(0)];
    result = await fs.read( fileDescriptor, buffer, 0, buffer.length-1, mark );
    await fs.close( fileDescriptor );
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce this behavior. From what I've tested, your function seems to work fine. Please correct me if I misunderstand but after running this test:

```
readNew(path.join(__dirname, 'test.txt'), 0).then((result) => {
    console.log('Read: ' + result.bytesRead + ' bytes');

    readNew(path.join(__dirname, 'test.txt'), result.bytesRead).then((result) => {
        console.log('Read: ' + result.bytesRead + ' bytes');
    });
});
```

The file test.txt in this case contains: A few bytes!

And this is my output:

`Read: 13 bytes`

`Read: 0 bytes`

Perhaps something goes wrong elsewhere in your code, such as supplying a position that is out of range.

**EDIT:**

Here's the full test using the `mz` library. It gives the same output as the other test using `fs-extra`.

```
const fs = require('mz/fs');
const path = require('path');

async function readNew(filename, mark) {
    var fileDescriptor = await fs.open(filename, "r");
    var buffer = new Buffer(32768);
    var result = await fs.read(fileDescriptor, buffer, 0, buffer.length, mark);
    await fs.close(fileDescriptor);
    return result;
}

readNew(path.join(__dirname, 'test.txt'), 0).then(([bytesRead, buffer]) => {
    console.log('Read: ' + bytesRead + ' bytes');

    readNew(path.join(__dirname, 'test.txt'), bytesRead).then(([bytesRead, buffer]) => {
        console.log('Read: ' + bytesRead + ' bytes');
    });
});
```

Comment: that's extremely odd - especially as I'm getting the problem, and the hacky code I provided fixed it - I'll have to do some more investigation.  I appreciate the effort!

Comment: I'm using the mz version of fs, to get promises - I wonder if it's node or package version.

Comment: I see. In the test case I used the ``fs-extra`` package which does the same thing by providing a promise wrapper for the native fs module. Perhaps the implementations differ, which could explain this discrepancy. I would expect both to behave like their native counterparts though.

Comment: @DarrenOakey I just tried my test with the same library as you are using. The library does behave a bit differently from ``fs-extra`` in the way that it returns its values, however, after adjusting the test to work with ``mz``, the function still behaves as it should.